# Como recibir datos datos del puerto serial RS232

Tags: c#

Necesito recibir datos de una balanza, ya logré mandar datos pero no logro recibir el dato de la balanza que está conectada por un RS232. ¿Cómo me podré conectar a esta balanza que me muestre el peso en un Label? ¿Cómo podría conectar esta balanza?

Este código  me sirve para comunicarme con los com pero no recibo nada de la balanza:

**Código**

```
 public partial class FormInicio : Form
    {
        public FormInicio()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        }
        private void puertosDisponibles()
        {
            foreach (string puertoDis in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                cmbPuertos.Items.Add(puertoDis);
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            puertosDisponibles();
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
        }
        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string datorx=serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            txtRx.Text = datorx.Trim();
        }
        private void cmbPuertos_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = cmbPuertos.Text;
            cmbPuertos.Enabled = false;
            try
            {
                serialPort1.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Selecciones otro puerto", "Puerto no disponible");
                cmbPuertos.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        private void btnEnviar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort1.Write(txtTx.Text.Trim());
                txtTx.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se puedo enviar la información", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Tengo el siguiente código que llamo en un textBox, pero no logro traer nada ¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal o como podría mostrar los datos de la balanza?

```
SerialPort spPuertoSerie = new SerialPort();
spPuertoSerie.PortName = "COM1";
spPuertoSerie.Handshake = Handshake.None;
spPuertoSerie.BaudRate = 9600;
spPuertoSerie.Parity = Parity.None;
spPuertoSerie.StopBits = StopBits.One;
spPuertoSerie.DataBits = 8;
```

Comment: que tipo de balanza es? yo trabaje con una que me manda el peso cuando se estabiliza y le mando datos para calibrarla o pedir datos continuos.

Comment: Avery Weigh-Tronix E1010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alguna vez trabajé con una balanza. Creo que el problema está en este método:

```
private void cmbPuertos_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    serialPort1.PortName = cmbPuertos.Text;
    cmbPuertos.Enabled = false;
    try
    {
        serialPort1.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selecciones otro puerto", "Puerto no disponible");
        cmbPuertos.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Asegurate que el manejador de eventos no lo asignes por la ventana de propiedades sino en cima de tu llamada al método Open(). DE ese modo quedaría así:

```
private void cmbPuertos_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    serialPort1.PortName = cmbPuertos.Text;
    serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
    serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
    serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
    serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    cmbPuertos.Enabled = false;
    try
    {
        serialPort1.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;
        serialPort1.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selecciones otro puerto", "Puerto no disponible");
        cmbPuertos.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Esepro resulte útil.

Comment: Amigo, Listo muchas gracias solo que la señal es intermitente

Comment: @Hackerman creo que deberías ver BaudRate y DataBits.

Comment: Oye lo que pasa es que viendo con el HyperTerminal los datos que me muestra la bascula son estos,   ST,GS,+      0kg  pero solo necesito que me muestre  0kg  fuera de eso me muestra de a uno primero la st,gs+ 0kg como puedo corregir esto tienes alguna idea de como lo puedo hacer

Comment: @Hackerman ¿Y qué tal si desglosas el valor con funciones de string?